# How do I create an ArrayList, so that I can record the position of each of these items?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to record the position of each rectangle that is drawn in this code. I am a beginner and to my understanding that can only be done through an arraylist. I do not know how to build the list to record each position that the rectangle moves into. This is what the code looks like at the moment.

```
Walker w;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  w = new Walker();
  background(0);
  frameRate(15);
}

void draw() {
  w.draw();
}

void mousePressed(){
  w.mousePressed();
}

class Walker {
  int x;
  int y;
  float direction;

  Walker() {
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;
  }

  void draw() {
    rect(x, y, 10, 10);

    if (direction<1) {    //North
      float choice = random(1);

      if (choice <0.4) {
        x=x+10;
      } else if (choice <0.8) {
        x=x-10;
      } else {
        y=y-10;
      }
    } else if (direction<2) {    //South
      float choice = random(1);

      if (choice <0.4) {
        x=x-10;
      } else if (choice <0.8) {
        x=x+10;
      } else {
        y=y+10;
      }
    } else if (direction<3) { // East
      float choice = random(1);

      if (choice < 0.4) {
        y=y+10;
      } else if (choice <0.8) {
        y=y-10;
      } else {
        x=x+10;
      }
    } else if (direction<4) { //West
      float choice = random(1);

      if (choice < 0.4) {
        y=y+10;
      } else if (choice <0.8) {
        y=y-10;
      } else {
        x=x-10;
      }
    }
  }
  void mousePressed() {
    direction = random(4);
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;
  }
}
```

Comment: _"can only be done through an arraylist"_ — No. There are many ways to store the positions you want to keep track of. A plain array, a List, a Map, a Set are some. If you're going to use a List it is not required to be an `ArrayList`; it could, for example, be a `LinkedList`. Your choice of how to store it depends on how you are going to ***use*** it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create an ArrayList under where you declared **direction**.

```
ArrayList<String> previousPoints = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Here is the import statement you'll need:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

This isn't the best way to do this but whenever you move your rectangle, given the x and y coordinate you can add them to the ArrayList previousPoints like so:

```
previousPoints.add("" + x + "," + y);
```

If you have the index you want in previousPoints you can retrieve the x and y: (Example index is 3)

```
String[] points = (previousPoints.get(3)).split(",");
int newX = Integer.parseInt(points[0]);
int newY = Integer.parseInt(points[1]);
```

I hope this helps Yianna!

Edit: important -> import

Comment: You shouldn't tie yourself to a particular implementation. If using a List (interface) and you've decided that, in this case, an ArrayList is a good List implementation _given what you're storing_ and _how you'll access it_ and _how many_ and _how it grows & shrinks_ then declare `List<String> previousPoints = new ArrayList<String>();` ... if you're growing to a large number without bounds you probably want something different like `List<Point> previousPoints = new LinkedList<>(initialSize)`